Does the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given by $f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + (1-nx)^2}$ converge uniformly to its pointwise limit?

Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of functions $f_n : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + (1-nx)^2}, \text{ for all } x \in [0,1].$$

(i) Find the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
(ii) Does the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge uniformly to its pointwise limit?
My workings:
i) I got that the sequence converges pointwise to the function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$. I think this is correct, this is not where my confusion lies.
ii) If $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$, then for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ (with $N$ only depending on $\epsilon$) such that for $n\ge N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.
rough work:
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2 + (1-nx)^2} - 0\right| = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + (1-nx)^2} \le  \frac{1}{1 + (1-n)^2} \le \frac{1}{(1-n)^2}<\epsilon$
Here is where I am confused, and think there is a flaw in my logic.
At this stage I'd expect to rearrange to get something like $n>g(\epsilon)$, so I can start off my proof by saying "Choose $N>g(\epsilon)$..." but here I get:
$\frac{1}{(1-n)^2}<\epsilon$
$\frac{1}{\epsilon}<(1-n)^2$
$\pm \sqrt(\frac{1}{\epsilon})< 1-n$
$1 \pm \sqrt(\frac{1}{\epsilon}) > n$
which doesn't make any sense as I need $n>...$ not $n<...$.
Thank you in advance.

Why do you claim that$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}\leqslant\frac1{1+(1-n)^2}?$$

I thought this would be bigger since $x \le 1$, however, I can see now that this is a silly mistake due to the denominator changing too, sorry!

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=1$. Therefore, the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge uniformly to the null function.

Thank you for this, I have not heard of this rule before. Does it have a name so I can research it more? Thank you very much.

Which rule? All I did was to show, by the definition of uniform convergence, that you don't have uniform convergence.
